# flickering with timer on update panel

Tags: asp.net

I am using an update panel in which I have set a timer. The problem is whenever the timer is changed It seems all of the update panel gets refreshed and there is flickering due to which I cannot select the values in the dropdown. How can I solve this problem.

here is my code.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" Text="Remaining Time" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblTimeSpan" Visible="false" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRemainingTime" Text="" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                <asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" OnTick="Timer1_Tick" Enabled="true" Interval="1000" ></asp:Timer>`//Timer`
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Timer1" EventName="Tick" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Are your labels also getting their content updated when Updatepanel refreshes ?? Where do you set the content for labels??

Comment: I have changed timer only on the code behind. drop down is on another update panel but it also gets refreshed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To Isolate the UpdatePanels from each other, set the property: `UpdateMode` to `Conditional`  for every update panel. After that define Triggers for your update Panels.

Example:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
     <ContentTemplate> 
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" /><br /> 
         <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Update Panel 1" 
         OnClick="Button1_Click" />         
     </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers> 
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click" /> 
   </Triggers> 
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

// IInd Update Panel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
 <ContentTemplate> 
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" ForeColor="red" /> 
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Update Panel 2" 
         OnClick="Button2_Click" /> 
 </ContentTemplate> 
 <Triggers> 
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button2" EventName="Click" /> 
 </Triggers> 
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Now the click events:

// Button Click 1

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(); 

    }
```

// Button Click 2

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
     Label2.Text = DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString(); 
}
```

As you can verify now, ***when you click on `Button1`, Only the First UpdatePanel is refreshed. It won't have any effect on 2nd Update Panel*** [ UpdatePanel2 ]

***Similary, click on `Button2`, only 2nd UpdatePanel will be refreshed. The First UpdatePanel will not refresh.***

So, In your case, set UpdateMode="Conditional" for the updatePanel containing the dropdownlist. And make sure the Triggers defined [ Controls here ] for your 2nd Update panel is not contained in firstUpdatePanel.